# How to speed up solution of system of recurrence equations

Tags: numerics, recursion, performance-tuning

I was wondering how I can improve the speed on this method for solving a particular system of coupled recurrence equations. The system is 
$$
\begin{align*}
&V(m)=\alpha + \beta V(m+1)+\beta \sum_{f=1}^4 Z(m+1,f)\\
&U(f)=\gamma +\beta U(f+1)+\beta \sum_{m=1}^4 Z(m,f+1)\\
&Z(m,f)=\zeta + \beta (Z(m+1,f+1)+U(f+1)+V(m+1))\\
&V(4)=U(4)=Z(4,f)=Z(m,4)=0.
\end{align*}
$$

And the solution I programmed is

```
T = 5;
β = .95;   
α = .3;   
γ = .2;   
ζ = α + γ + .3;   
V[T] = U[T] = 0.;

Do[Z[m, T] = 0., {m, 1, T}]    
Do[Z[T, f] = 0., {f, 1, T}]

Do[V[m] = α + β V[m + 1] + β Sum[
     Z[m + 1, f], {f, 1, T}], {m, T - 1, 1, -1}]   
Do[U[f] = γ + β U[f + 1] + β Sum[Z[m, f + 1], {m, 1, T}], {f, T - 1, 1, -1}]

Do[Z[m, f] = 
   Z[m, f] /. 
    NSolve[Z[m, f] == ζ + β (Z[m + 1, f + 1] + V[m + 1] + U[f + 1]), 
      Z[m, f], Reals][[1]], {m, T - 1, 1, -1}, {f, T - 1, 1, -1}]
```

Notice that I have to solve for the values of Z, otherwise I get a recursion depth error.

I need to solve a similar system as this one but with m and f ranging from 1 to 55, just wanted to know if there exists a more efficient way because with T=7, my computer lasts about 5 minutes to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: These equations are unusual because the values of U, V, and Z depend only on future values of U, V and Z. In any case the right tool for this problem is the RecurrenceTable feature documented at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html?q=RecurrenceTable

Comment: Thanks for the reference. However, I get a strange error when I code `RecurrenceTable[{
V[m]==\[Alpha]+\[Beta] V[m+1]+\[Beta] Sum[Z[m+1,f],{f,1,4}],
U[f]==\[Gamma]+\[Beta] U[f+1]+\[Beta] Sum[Z[m,f+1],{m,1,4}],
Z[m,f]==\[Zeta]+\[Beta] Z[m+1,f+1]+\[Beta] U[f+1]+\[Beta] V[m+1],
V[T]==0,U[T]==0,Z[4,1]==Z[4,2]==Z[4,3]==Z[4,4]==Z[3,4]==Z[2,4]==Z[1,4]==0},
{V,U,Z},{m,1,T-1},{f,1,T-1}]` with `T=4` and `\[Beta]=.95`, `\[Alpha]=\[Gamma]=\[Zeta]=.3`. The error says "RecurrenceTable::dvlen: -- Message text not found -- (V[m]) (2) >>". I'm using Mathematica 10.1 on a Mac.